# C# Adjust DateTime based on TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Hello I keep two times stored in the database in military time based on the timezone of a user (Ex: Start: 08:00 - End: 14:00).  I also keep the user's timezone stored in the database in the following format "Central Time (US and Canada) (GMT -06:00)"

So in the example above the user's quiet times are 8:00am to 2:00pm Central Time.  If the user enters 12:00 - 10:00 I simple add a day to the lower number so it would be 1/1/2013 12:00pm - 1/2/2013 10:00am.  I am using the following method to see if the server time falls within that range.  My question is, how can I pass in the timezone and make sure I see if it falls within that range in the user's set timezone?

```
private static bool IsInQuietTime(string startDate, string endDate)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startDate) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endDate)) return false;
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var sDate = DateTime.Parse(now.ToString("M/d/yyyy " + startDate));
            var eDate = DateTime.Parse(now.ToString("M/d/yyyy " + endDate));
            if (eDate <= sDate)
                eDate = eDate.AddDays(1);
            return now.Ticks >= sDate.Ticks && now.Ticks <= eDate.Ticks;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You really should store UTC in the database and then just do your server compare with that. Then use the TimeZoneInfo class to convert to the user's time when you need to present the data to the user.

Comment: @Seph - Actually, this is one of the use cases for *not* storing as UTC.  As the OP stated, the time is stored without a date.  I assume it recurs daily.  If you stored as UTC, you would be striping out the intent of the user.  The effect would be that when DST changed, the user would find their "quiet time" has shifted an hour.  Ever find your appointments or alarm clock off by an hour after DST changes?  That is why.

Comment: @MattJohnson or you can just use `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` and convert the time to non-DST and then to UTC and store that. I have never encountered a single DST problem using this approach in my applications (and they're used globally). If a user wants to change timezones then you convert from the old value to the new value and store that new time. The server is going to do checks a whole lot more frequently than the user will edit/view the time.

Comment: @Seph Thanks for the feedback.  Would you please show an answer that takes this approach?  I can envision what you are describing, but it seems like it would be more complicated.  The main concern I have is maintaining the intent of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do this:

```
private static bool NowInTimeRange(string startTimeString, string endTimeString, string timeZoneId)
{
    // convert to timespan
    var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(startTimeString);
    var endTime = TimeSpan.Parse(endTimeString);

    // what time is it in the timezone specified?
    var now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, timeZoneId);

    // if they are in order, are we between the times specified?
    if (startTime <= endTime)
        return now.TimeOfDay >= startTime && now.TimeOfDay <= endTime;

    // when not in order, just see if either one of them matches.
    return now.TimeOfDay >= startTime || now.TimeOfDay <= endTime;
}
```

Notice, I don't manipulate the time by adding a day - I simply rely on the comparison to work in the way the user expressed it.

Also, the value you said you were storing for the user is not a time zone id.  That's coming from `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName`.  Make sure you are working with values obtained from `TimeZoneInfo.Id` instead.

Here is how you would use this method:

```
var quietTime = NowInTimeRange("08:00", "14:00", "Central Standard Time");
```

And it will work equally as well if the times are out of sequence:

```
var quietTime = NowInTimeRange("12:00", "10:00", "Central Standard Time");
```